# header file not accessible in makefile

Tags: c++, makefile, include-path

I have one directory called MAKE and four sub directory's source and header bin and obj. source contains cpp files and header contains one header file which is included in all three cpp files.
I am trying to create a make file.
i am trying to access the source and header files from their respective directories. my current directory is MAKE(where my make file is present).

I am not able to access header file from my header directory.
Where am i going wrong ??
ERROR is xxxx.h no such file or directory . How should i modify the code ?

```
     CC = g++
     TARGET = vineeth

     CFLAGS   = -Wall

     LINKER   = g++ -o


    SRCDIR   = source
    HEADDIR  = header
    OBJDIR   = obj
    BINDIR   = bin

    SOURCES  := $(wildcard $(SRCDIR)/*.cpp)
    INCLUDES := $(wildcard $(HEADDIR)/*.h)
    OBJECTS  := $(SOURCES:$(SRCDIR)/%.cpp=$(OBJDIR)/%.o)


    $(BINDIR)/$(TARGET): $(OBJECTS)
         $(LINKER) $@ $(LFLAGS) $(OBJECTS)
         @echo "Linking complete!"

    $(OBJECTS): $(OBJDIR)/%.o : $(SRCDIR)/%.cpp
         @$(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@
         @echo "Compiled "$<" successfully!"
```

Comment: Perhaps add an include path to the compile step `@$(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@ -I$(HEADDIR)`

Comment: Also it would be helpful if you copied the *exact* error message you are getting into your question.

Comment: IT WORKED IT WORKED HURRAY !!! Thank you so much @shuttle87